Don't have permission to view all the namespaces in the cluster
I tried to add gitlab-agent to the environment and select the namespace and flux customization there, but I get errors

I'm using the Gitlab hosted version of Self-Manager on Kubernetes.
Install command gitlab-agent
helm upgrade --install h gitlab/gitlab-agent \
    --namespace gitlab-agent-h \
    --create-namespace \
    --set image.tag=v17.2.2 \
    --set config.token=token \
    --set config.kasAddress=wss://kas.domain.com

Configuration gitlab-agent to path .gitlab/agents/my-agent/config.yaml in repository
user_access:
  access_as:
    agent: {}
  groups:
    - id: LearnHub
    - id: LearnHub/Frontend
    - id: LearnHub/Identity
ci_access:
  groups:
    - id: LearnHub
    - id: LearnHub/Frontend
    - id: LearnHub/Identity


Install command flux
flux bootstrap gitlab \
--hostname=gitlab.domain.com \
--owner=Flux-LearnHub \
--repository=Flux \
--branch=main \
--path=clusters/production \
--deploy-token-auth

Adding a repository
flux create source git learnhub-mainpage \
  --url=https://gitlab.domain.com/learnhub/frontend/mainpage.git \
  --branch=main \
  --interval=1m \
  --namespace=flux-system \
  --username=username \
  --password=token

flux create kustomization learnhub-mainpage-kustomization \
  --source=GitRepository/learnhub-mainpage.flux-system \
  --path="./manifests" \
  --prune=true \
  --interval=5m \
  --namespace=flux-system

And I don’t see Flux customization or namespace in the selection
I tried to manually grant the gitlab-agent cluster admin role for testing
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: gitlab-agent-cluster-admin
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: learnhub-gitlab-agent # name ServiceAccount
  namespace: gitlab-agent

And I made sure that gitlab-agent has rights to all namespaces, but still nothing appears in the list, tell me how to fix this.
I also noticed that all requests that access gitlab kas return with error 401, and this specifically applies to those requests for which I created a question.
https://kas.domain.com/k8s-proxy/api/v1/namespaces
https://kas.domain.com/k8s-proxy/apis/kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1/namespaces/gitlab-agent/kustomizations
https://kas.domain.com/k8s-proxy/apis/helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1/namespaces/gitlab-agent/helmreleases

General answer
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "GitLab Agent Server: Unauthorized: no valid credentials provided",
  "reason": "Unauthorized",
  "code": 401
}


Consider to ask sys-admin questions (e.g. about installation of pre-made software) on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

In my case there was a problem with separation domains as stated in the answer, the solution of merging the domain above kas.domain.com and gitlab.domain.com into 1 domain helped me.
And in this case, the request will correspond to this url.
https://gitlab.domain.com/k8s-proxy/api/v1/namespaces

Instead
https://kas.domain.com/k8s-proxy/api/v1/namespaces

The problem I had was that if I just had 2 ingress that are responsible for gitlab and kas, the web server would access the old domain and get a 404. This was fixed by such parameters when updating gitlab.
--set global.hosts.kas.name=gitlab.domain.com

helm chart kas built into helm chart gitlab
And after the above action, we change the ingress by merging 2 domains into 1 and we get something similar.
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gitlab-ingress
  namespace: gitlab
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: gitlab.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: gitlab-webservice-default
                port:
                  number: 8181
          - path: /k8s-proxy/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: gitlab-kas
                port:
                  number: 8154
          - path: /kas
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: gitlab-kas
                port:
                  number: 8150
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - gitlab.domain.com
      secretName: gitlab-tls


Other possible problems associated with this error

From Gitlab we have the recommendation below:
An error like GitLab Agent Server: Unauthorized. Trace ID: <...> on the Dashboard for Kubernetes page might be caused by one of the following:

The user_access entry in the agent configuration file doesn’t exist or is wrong. 
To resolve, see Grant users Kubernetes access.

There are multiple _gitlab_kas cookies in the browser and sent to KAS. The most likely cause is multiple GitLab instances hosted on the same site.

For example, gitlab.com set a _gitlab_kas cookie targeted for kas.gitlab.com, but the cookie is also sent to kas.staging.gitlab.com, which causes the error on staging.gitlab.com.
To temporarily resolve, delete the _gitlab_kas cookie for gitlab.com from the browser cookie store. Issue 418998 proposes a fix for this known issue.

GitLab and KAS run on different sites. For example, GitLab on gitlab.example.com and KAS on kas.example.com. GitLab does not support this use case. For details, see issue 416436.

Reference link:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/troubleshooting.html

I checked all the options you described except merging the domain kas.example.com and gitlab.example.com, because even if I create an ingress and change the URL in the gitlab agent, I will not be able to affect the domain to which the web service makes requests. All other options did not help. Thank you

So you have different address?

If you are referring to a mirror of the main domain, then no. If you are referring to splitting the domain into kas.domain.com and gitlab.domain.com, then yes, they are separated by different subdomains.

Yes. I was saying about different subdomains.
